# ZXing IntentResult cannot resolve to type

Tags: java, android, zxing

I'm trying to use Zxing in my Android app.  I've added the small library [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent) and have followed the instructions but when I try to create an IntentResult I get: IntentResult cannot be resolved to a type.  Can someone point out what stupid mistake I'm making here? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to also add [this](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentResult.java) IntentResult class to the project.

Comment: Really, you want to add both classes in that module, or the .jar file that it compiles for you.

Comment: Right, you should mention that on the wiki page: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent